# Sending an email correctly using javamail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have an annoying problem. You see, I have created a program that basically can send files, grab files, and run commands on other computers where the program is running. I do this by exchanging messages and files through an unprotected email address using IMAP. Well, my school doesn't have some sort of online-repository to exchange files or send messages to other people, so I am using this purely for my middle school. Well, considering the fact that it works when I have the program running on my laptop and then my mom's computer, but I can't send any sort of message from school,I think it might have to something with the school firewall. NOTE: I CAN connect to the email, but I can't send any sort of email to it. I get a  "java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" error when I try to click the "Send File", "Grab File", or ""Command" button in school, because those all involve sending messages. EDIT - I can't post pictures yet, as I just joined StackOverflow. Sorry :( but I can't show you what the program looks like. EDIT AGAIN - One more vote and I can add the picture!

Well, here is the code I use for sending a simple message such as an error message or a request to run a command. I use the same method for sending a file too:

```
public void sendMessage(String subject,String message) {
    try {
         Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
          Session sesh = Session.getInstance(props,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(email, pass);
                     }
                  });
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(sesh);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EmailGUI.gui.getEmail()));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        msg.setSubject(EmailGUI.gui.encrypt(subject + "AbC" + uuid.toString().replaceAll("-","")));
        Multipart body = new MimeMultipart();
        MimeBodyPart attach = new MimeBodyPart();
        attach.setContent(encrypt(message), "TEXT/PLAIN");
            body.addBodyPart(attach);
            msg.setContent(body);
            Transport.send(msg);
            field.setText("");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        out.write("Failed to send message.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? (My school uses Java 7 Update 62 if that helps)

Comment: Does the school have its own SMTP server?  The firewall may be blocking internal machines from connecting to external SMTP servers.  Use the school's SMTP server instead of the gmail one.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I don't know if the school has its own SMTP server. How might I go about finding that server? (Sorry if I sound dumb I only know java as a programming language)

Comment: One way would be to ask the shool's sysadmin.  What sort of email system do you have at the school?  Is it a webmail system, or can people run normal email clients?  If the latter, then just look at the config settings of any working email client.  There may be other issues you need to resolve, such as needing an email account on the server. Also the "From" address may need to be a school one if the server doesn't have relaying enabled (which is usually the case).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Here is what I know if it helps. 1: I cannot ask my school's sysadmin as he probably will think I am trying to hack the school(I told him about a way to get around the web filter a week ago) 2: My school uses windows 7 computers, has Lightspeed Systems as a web filter, and I think might have their own email server as u suggested, as they use \@sprise.com for staff email addresses. I highly doubt I could get access to that though unless you have an idea :)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Ok, so I was reading through gmail's message-sending requirements, and I have everything, but it said that if one port (AKA 587 in my case) does not work, try the other (AKA 465). So I'll try that! Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Your program is connecting directly to Gmail, so no school mail server is involved.  Most likely your school has a firewall that's blocking the request.  The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide some clues.